# How to sort R vector according to a vector in indices

Tags: r

I get how to reorder test so that the 13th element of the vector goes first then 7th second as per the ind order. BUT, how do I do the reverse so 'blah1' would become the 13th element of the new vector? Then the next element 'blah1' would then become the 7th element of the new vector... and so on...

> test
>    [1] "blah1" "blah1" "blah1" "blah1" "blah2" "blah2" "blah2" "blah2" "blah2" "blah2" "blah2" "blah2" "blah2"
>   ind
>    [1] 13  7  3 10  5  6  4  2 12  9  1 11  8
>   test[ind]
>    [1] "blah2" "blah2" "blah1" "blah2" "blah2" "blah2" "blah1" "blah1" "blah2" "blah2" "blah1" "blah2" "blah2"

OR alternatively

v <- c('a','b','c')
ind <- c(3,2,1)

new v <- somefunction(v, ind)

new v
'c','b','a'

Get it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi try this with your later vectors v and ind

```
v[order(ind)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `rev()` function, it reverses the vector elements

```
  data <- c("a","b","c")
  new_Data <- rev(data)
```

Comment: The question is about using the `ind`

Answer (score 0):

You can use sort function also

```
v[sort(ind,decreasing = T)]
```